# Does anyone know how to stop T4 (tt) templates from regerating every single file? Is there a way to flag certain files?

Tags: t4

So the tt templates will regenerate every file whenever you save. Now, great, it generates files. However, I am making partial classes to extend other classes, but I only need the files that dont already exist for me generated. The ones that exist, I'd like to preserve. So far, I am finding not one solid solution googling the globe...

In my code below, the exception for finding existing files doesnt matter, because the template will start by deleting all files first. Then it regenerates.

It there a method like "onsave" that I can override?

```
// BEGIN CODE TO GENERATE EXTENSIONS
<#
foreach (EntityType entity in ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
{ 
 string fileName = entity.Name + ".Extension.cs";
 string filePath = this.Host.TemplateFile.Substring(0,this.Host.TemplateFile.LastIndexOf(@"\")); 
 filePath = filePath + @"\Extensions\" + fileName;
 if((File.Exists(filePath) && PreserveExistingExtensions == false) || !File.Exists(filePath))
 {
  fileManager.StartNewFile(fileName);
  BeginNamespace(namespaceName, code);
  bool entityHasNullableFKs = entity.NavigationProperties.Any(np => np.GetDependentProperties().Any(p=>ef.IsNullable(p)));
#>
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#>   
<#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class 
<#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
{
}
<#
EndNamespace(namespaceName);
 }
}
fileManager.Process();
#>
```

Comment: Why not check the file content with the generated code? From what I can see, you are controlling that process.

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar (partial classes) where I have one that is always generated, but the custom one will only be generated if it doesn't exist. This second one is created as starting class for customizations. I'll output two files like so:

1. MyClass.generated.cs
2. MyClass.cs

MyClass.cs will never be recreated, unless it doesn't exist. MyClass.generated.cs will always be recreated.

I use the [T4toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/) to do this, Oleg Sych has actually made this quite easy.

You can check out some sample T4 Templates I built [here](https://dotnetcodegen.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Source/Templates/). Specifically have a look at [this one](https://dotnetcodegen.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Source/Templates/ServiceContractGenerator.tt), it's a good example for generated partial classes where one needs to be created every time, and one is only created if it doesn't exist.

The main thing to look at is this line in the code:

```
    var requestBaseMessageCustom = new MessageTemplate(rootNamespace, serviceName + "Request");
    requestBaseMessageCustom.Output.File = "Messages/" + serviceName + "Request.cs";
    requestBaseMessageCustom.Output.PreserveExistingFile = true;
    requestBaseMessageCustom.Render();
```

Notice the property called `PreserveExistingFile`, that's the key.

Comment: You inherit from : Template in your MessageTemplate - what assembly does this reference??